# Getting the creation date of a file on Cygwin

Tags: shell, date, cygwin, stat

I'm trying to get the creation date of a file using console commands. I've managed to use this:

```
stat -c "%w" file
```

which outputs the date and time:

```
2015-05-01 09:33:22.503525000 -0400
```

But I'd like to extract only the date (without the time) from the result. Is there a way to do this using only stat, or do I have to separate the result using another command? And what might that command be?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that your shell is bash? That is cygwin's default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash:

```
date -d "@$(stat -c %W file)" +%F
```

Will do the trick. `%W` on stat returns the epoch date, `date +%F` converts it to a YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: You will have to use options in captal form, like:  `%W`, `%X`, `%Y`, `%Z`. Use of small letter options: `%w` `%x` `%y` `%z` will produce error.

Comment: If the answer was useful, I'd appreciate if you accepted it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
stat -c "%w" file | cut -d" " -f1
```

The output of `stat` will be piped into `cut` and the string will be cut at the first concurrence of a white space.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, It cuts the string to it's first occurrence of a white space.

Comment: is the pipe symbol really a pipe? so in a way, cut receives the output of stat and cuts the string at the first occurence of the white space?

Comment: Well, please include that description into your answer, just now I was reviewing it in the low quality queue. Including this explanation will prevent your answer from being deleted because containing too few details

Comment: It's a good tip, but I like the next answer better because it's a lot more flexible.

Comment: @Ghi102, For the next answer you are talking about:
You will have to use options in captal form, like:  `%W`, `%X`, `%Y`, `%Z`. Use of small letter options: `%w` `%x` `%y` `%z` will produce error.

And in my answer, it will never produce error and the meaning of `%w` `%W` is unchanged i.e you can use both options as they are meant for by `stat` command i.e `%w` for date and `%W` for seconds.